# Simplify a Formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

Current Formula:

`=IF(SUM(C8:C14)>=8, "10", IF(SUM(C8:C14)=14, "10", IF(SUM(C8:C14)=12, "10", IF(SUM(C8:C14)=6, "6", IF(SUM(C8:C14)=4, "4", IF(SUM(C8:C14)=2, "2", IF(SUM(C8:C14)=0, "0",)))))))`

Which WORKS (and is great) but due to its complexity, Google Sheets doesn't recognize the cell's total (displays "0") and therefore the entire sheet is off. Basically, I just need a formula that states 0=0, 2=2, 4=4, 6=6, 8=10, 10=10, 12=10, and 14=10.

Comment: If you use `"` around a number you tell it to be seen as text. Simply remove them. Also, both `14` and `12` are `>=8` and all should result in `10`, so these are unnecessary: `=IF(SUM(C8:C14)>=8, 10, IF(SUM(C8:C14)=6, 6, IF(SUM(C8:C14)=4, 4, IF(SUM(C8:C14)=2, 2, IF(SUM(C8:C14)=0, 0)))))`. PS if your sum results in <=8 not equal to `2`, `4` or `6` it returns `FALSE` is that desirable?

Answer (score 1):

Make a table as follows
[image]

The formula will be

```
=vlookup(sum(C8:C14),F1:G8,2,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple IF statement like this?

=IF(SUM(C8:C14)>=8, 10, SUM(C8:C14))

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUM(C8:C14), {SEQUENCE(8,1,,2), {0;2;4;6;10;10;10;10}}, 2, 1)
```